# Two moderators can overlap lock messages

Tags: bug, moderators, locked-posts

Ran into an interesting situation on a question. Bhargav Rao and I happened to be looking at [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054753/c-read-memory-faild) which was being vandalized/rolled back. 5 seconds apart, we both [issued a lock](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65054753/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries). Mine took (being first) but somehow his lock message was also taken.

[image: Two locks are better than wuh-huh-nnn]

Easily fixed by unlocking and re-locking, but strange it allowed a second message.

Comment: I also noticed that in the question history it says 'notice removed' twice.

Comment: Looks like code written by professional electrician - you always want to lock power switch/box with your own lock so it can't be switched/opened by mistake while you are dealing with wires... :)

Comment: There are disputes about this question's lock notice being resolved at this time.  It is not currently accepting new lock notices.

Comment: Cool. I wonder how many years it will take before this happens again :)

Comment: Something something programmer jokes, something, race condition, something 3 things.

Comment: @Gimby For the record, it took .083 years, or exactly one month, before [this bug happened again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359017/323179).